# Do you have to finish your food in the sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, eating

If you took a big bite of bread while in the sukkah (during the holiday of Sukkot), are you allowed to step outside and finish eating what's already in your mouth?

Comment: eating usually encompasses chewing and hannas goran(swallowing ) in halacha

Comment: @sam, do you have a source for that statement?

Comment: yodea , see Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 50:5

Answer (score 1):

> ...and even if one has food in one's mouth and one began chewing when one leaves the Sukkah one shouldn't continue chewing until one returns to the Sukkah.
>
> *[Yalkut Yosef (Moadim pg 143), Halichot Olam 2:pg. 271, Meiri Sukka 26b "Hamishnah Hachamishit", Shaar Hatziyun 639:29]*

(Source: [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Eating_in_the_Sukkah#If_one_is_in_the_middle_of_a_meal))

Comment: Why can't you chew outside the Sukkah if you swallow inside the Sukkah?

Comment: Maybe because by chewing there's a bigger chance that he might swallow by mistake?

Comment: Sure, but is that a real Gezera or just personal advice of those rabbis?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea.